# instantiate chaincode instantiate proposal was bad

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I was able to install the chaincode and instantiate successfully. When I was trying to make some changes to the chaincode and redeploy, am continuously getting this error while instantiating the chaincode

instantiatingchaincode - instantiate proposal was bad
failed to order transaction

I tried to delete docker containers and install chaincode from start but no success..
I believe its something do with old images of chaincode.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by
removing the docker containers, remove hfc and re-install and instantiate. It works now.